# Decrypt p7m File Using C#?

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption, pkcs#7

I have a .p7m (application/pkcs7-mime) encrypted file on my hard drive, and the associated Private Key it was encrypted with. It is encrypted with AES (128bit) and enveloped with RSA (1024bit). I have successfully imported the key from my key store but I dont know how i would go about using it to decrypt a .p7m file. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may found interesting this free project, a web service to work with p7m files: http://igg.me/at/p7m-online-reader

Comment: An online p7m decrypter?  Kinda defeats the purpose, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you start with the [EnvelopedCms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f73feezf(v=VS.90).aspx) class and maybe use the Decode () method followed by the Decrypt method. It is hard to figure out from the documentation, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180951%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) may help.

Comment: Thanks but I am going to give BouncyCastle a go.